Doubt on arithmetic of segment (Foundations of Geometry)
I am studying Hilbert's famous book, "Foundations of Geometry". After proving Pascal's theorem, Hilbert builds an arithmetic of segments, he defines the sum of two segments and the product of two segments.
In the proof of the commutative property of the multiplication of segments, Hilbert makes use of Pascal's theorem: after having constructed the segments $ab$ and $ba$ as described above, he writes:
"by Pascal's Theorem, in view of the parallelism of the auxiliary lines shown in figure, the segment $ba$ coincides with the previously constructed segment $ab$".
What I do not understand is why the parallelism of the two dotted lines is so important to conclude that $ab=ba$. And, actually, why can we apply Pascal's Theorem? Referring to my drawing below, we do not know that $B'=B''$; this is what we want to show, while Hilbert seems assuming it when applying the theorem. What am I missing?
Thanks for any answer and help!



What Hilbert was trying to do is proving $B'C \parallel C'B$ by Pascal's theorem, which implies $B' = B''$ by the definition of $B''.$ Specifically, he used $A'C \parallel C'A$ and $A'B \parallel B'A$ for the assumption of Pascal's theorem.

Then $B'$ must coincide with $B''$ because if it were not so, then there would exist two line parallel to the same line $BC'$ and passing through the same point $C$, while the fact that $AC'$ and $A'C$ are parallel does not follow from Pascal's Theorem, but from the construction. Right?

@Steppenwolf what you're saying is correct although unnecessarily complicated. If you want to prove that $B'$ is the unique point satisfying the construction for $ba$ (being parallel), then you only need to prove that it satisfies the condition. You don't need to go: let $B''$ be the unique..., if $B' \neq B''$, then it would contradict the uniqueness of..., therefore $B' = B''$.

Okk, thank you!
